# Vuforia: image sticks to the screen when the marker is lost

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

When Vuforia loses the marker, the 3D model which was "attached" to the marker is sticking to the screen. How to make it disappear if the marker tracking is lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the script where you have:

```
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    {
        OnTrackingFound();
    }
    else
    {
        OnTrackingLost();
    }
}
```

Then, implement OnTrackingLost:

```
void OnTrackingLost()
{
     model.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This version didn't work for me, maybe because I use legacy Vuforia? But I found similar example which works for me: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-play-audio-when-targets-get-detected

Comment: I don't think there is any legacy version, at least none that I have heard of. The link you provide shows the same code as mine. ITrackableEventHandler is the interface that requires OnTrackableStateChanged implementation. In the Vuforia example it would be DefaultTrackableEventHandler or something close (can't remember). But all in all, you got it.